# Calculating the mean and variance of a Gaussian from its density

Tags: normal-distribution, markov-chains, variance, means

I was reading this [post](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models/#nice) where the Markov Chain is represented as:

[image]

Can someone please explain how the mean and the variance can be calculated from the above equation?

PS: I know about Gaussian, and all the related equations but somehow I am not able to figure out the math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (univariate) Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ has density proportional to
$$
\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
=\exp\left(-\frac{(x^2-2\mu x+\mu^2)}{2\sigma^2}\right).\tag1
$$
If you have a univariate Gaussian distribution whose density is proportional to
$$\exp\left(-\frac12(ax^2 -bx + c)\right),\tag2$$
then you obtain the mean and variance of your distribution by matching coefficients on $x^2$ and $x$ between (1) and (2). This gives the system of equations
$$
-\frac1{2\sigma^2}=-\frac a2\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}=\frac b2,
$$
which you can solve for $$\sigma^2=\frac1a\qquad\text{and}\qquad\mu=\frac b{2a}.$$
In your example this recipe will give you the conditional distribution for $x_{t-1}$ given $x_t$ and $x_0$.